# How to get server-side parameters using jQuery UI remote?

Tags: php

I have a php ajax script that is getting called by some jQuery, and I can not seem to get the parameters that are being passed.  Here is the example I am working from: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote

In my php side, I did something like this just to see what my parameters are:

```
error_log ("1) ".var_dump($_GET));
error_log ("2) ".var_dump($_POST));
error_log ("3) ".var_dump($_REQUEST));
```

But they all return empty.  Can that be? How can I get at the parameters that are being passed?

Thanks!!

Here is my js:

```
$(function()
{
$( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
    source: "/problems/get_categories_ajax.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) 
    {
        log( ui.item ?
            "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var_dump` ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)) does not return the dump, it outputs just like `echo`. Use `print_r` ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)) with the second param set to `true`

```
error_log ("1) ".print_r($_GET, true));
error_log ("2) ".print_r($_POST, true));
error_log ("3) ".print_r($_REQUEST, true));
```

Comment: @GeekedOut Then you need to show some JS so we can see what you are actually passing. That's assuming that in using `print_r` properly, you're seeing "1) 2) 3)" in your log...

Comment: do you know how to massage the output on the server side in order to get it displayed on the front end?  :)

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking. You can `echo` anything back to the front end, but the response is being used by autocomplete which is expecting you to send a response it knows how to handle...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4559/discussion-between-geekedout-and-jaaulde)

Comment: yeah I echo the output, but it doesn't get displayed in the dropdown right below the form for some reason.